# Why notification access does not work in Android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have placed a button with a setonclicklisenet and I want a notification to be sent when I click the button but it is not working what is the problem?I am not even asked any android question regarding access permission

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIF_TEST"
    lateinit var btnNofig:Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        init()
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun init(){
        bindView()
        createNotificationChannel()
        btnNofig.setOnClickListener  {
            // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            val intent = Intent(this, AlertDetails::class.java).apply {
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            }
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setContentText("this is a test")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(1, builder.build())
            }
        }
    }
    fun bindView(){
        btnNofig = findViewById(R.id.btnNotification)
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
            val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNotification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

What should be done?

Comment: You need to look into your logcat, you may find there error logs indicating cause of the error. Also check if you have the required permission : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Comment: android 13 requires ask use if they want notifications

Answer (score 0):

You need to Pass CHANNEL_ID NotificationCompat.Builder to tell builder which channel this notification meant for

From

```
var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,)
```

To

```
var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
```